# the banks would probably be willing to take a haircut on the rest

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The banks would probably be willing to take a haircut on the rest.

https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/e658c2f9268b44859830a022587e301c

'take a haircut on sth' means what?

The 'take' in 'take a haircut' means the 'take' in 'take a shower': do ?

In short, my questions are:

1. the literal meaning of the 'take a haircut'
2. the figurative meaning of the 'take a haircut'

Comment: @Michael Harvey Why did you remove your perfectly good answer? And why was this question downvoted, presumably by someone else.

Comment: @Lambie - at a guess, it may have been downvoted for lack of research, since Googling 'haircut meaning finance' took me 30 seconds approximately.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But I can see the person did try. I mean....it is a very useful term and should not be dv'ed. Not everyone can google right, right off the bat, especially when a thing seems odd. haircut + finance, sure.

Comment: Even if you just google "what does take a haircut mean", you get the correct answer right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People in the world of business finance and investment use a number of metaphors derived from personal grooming.

If a person **literally** takes (or gets) a haircut, they go to a barber's or hairdresser's shop to have their hair cut into a neat style.

If a person or company **figuratively** takes (or gets) a haircut in connection with an investment they have made, this usually means they experience, because of market conditions, a (percentage) difference between an asset's market value and the amount that can be used as collateral for a loan. This percentage is called the 'haircut'. The asset's collateral value has been trimmed as a barber trims a customer's hair.

> For example, if a person needs a $10,000 loan and wants to use their
> $10,000 stock portfolio as collateral, the bank is more likely to
> recognize the $10,000 portfolio as worth only $5,000 in collateral.
> The $5,000 or 50% reduction in the asset's value, for collateral
> purposes, is called the haircut. Should the person's stock portfolio
> decline in value, they may still have sufficient collateral for the
> amount of debt issued.

[Haircut (Investopedia)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/haircut.asp)

Another, less often used, meaning is to do with a market maker's 'spread'. The term haircut is used since the market maker's spreads are so thin. A market maker may 'trim' (deduct and retain) a very small fee from proceeds collected as part of providing liquidity in markets or facilitating trades.

Another term is 'take a bath'. This slang term refers to an investor who experiences a significant loss from an investment. Investors whose shares decline substantially are said to have taken a bath.

In the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, an investment or new business can be said to 'wash its face' if, in the current short term, it either breaks even, or makes a small profit.

Comment: @Lambie - as I linked and quoted.

Comment: @Lambie - thanks for the heads-up; moved link.